# Windows Vista Nested Desktop Folders Problem

Tags: windows-vista

I have no idea how, nor when this happened, and it's started to really quite annoy me.

When navigating through Explorer, by clicking on Icons I have
`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop` (Icon is the blue special Desktop icon), which contains the items I see on my Desktop.
I then have the following folder:
`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop` (Icon is the standard yellow folder icon), which contains many program shortcuts, and is completely separate from the other `C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop`

Then in the Yellow Icon Desktop I have the sub-folder Desktop with the blue icon that is a direct mirror of the blue `C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop` folder (as in a new folder / file shows up in both).

In explorer when I directly type

`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop`

I am taken to the Yellow folder version.

If I go to

`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Desktop`

I am taken to the Blue folder version.

Finally, from `cmd`
cd'ing to

`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop`

takes me to the Yellow folder version

whilst

`C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Desktop`

takes me to the blue folder version.

How on earth can I get rid of the yellow folder version leaving the blue C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop. I can't delete either as it says they're in use.

UPDATE:
Ok, so it looks like doing a `dir` from `cmd` lists only one Desktop folder - the Yellow one. 
In addition, it looks like I can't delete either of them (given that they both contain my 'Desktop'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article, you may have to use the hidden Admin account to delete the folders

http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/337152-please-help-multiple-desktop-folder-icons-cannot-rid.html

Comment: Thanks for the link - I have no idea why that didn't show up in my many google searches on this issue. I ended up following method two in the tutorial linked to from that forum post. Then I had to follow their other tutorial to restore the blue icon. But essentially, that method works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move all the files on both folders to a temporary location, change the user folder location to a temporary location using this guide:
http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/107990-personal-user-shell-folders-move-location.html
And then change it back to C:\Users\, that should fix it.

Comment: Again, a good tutorial, although the default path is not just C:\Users but C:\Users\User-Name\{Problem Folder, in my case Desktop}.

Comment: I used "vista nested desktop folders" as my search terms.